# Как оперировать элементами после наследия ?

Tags: c#

Хочу уточнить,можно ли оперировать значениями,как в обычном List,после наследия в этом коде,если да,то прошу подсказать,как же это происходить будет в Main. Изначально задание звучит: создайте пользовательскую коллекцию обобщенного типа на основе одной из стандартных коллекций. Я выбрал List. Правильный ли этот подход ?

```
public class Employee
{
    public int ID { get; protected set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string SecondName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string FullName
    {
        get { return string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", SecondName, FirstName, MiddleName); }
    }
    public List<string> PhoneNumbers { get; private set; }

    public Employee(string secondName, string firstName, string middleName)
    {
        this.ID = Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode();
        this.FirstName = firstName;
        this.SecondName = secondName;
        this.MiddleName = middleName;
        this.PhoneNumbers = new List<string>();
    }
}
public class EmployeeCollection : List<Employee>
{
    public Employee[] FindByName(string firstName, string secondName, string middleName)
    {
        return this.Where(e => e.FirstName == firstName && e.SecondName == secondName && e.MiddleName == middleName).ToArray();
    }
    public Employee[] FindByPhone(string number)
    {
        return this.Where(e => e.PhoneNumbers.Contains(number)).ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: Всё правильно. Можно работать как с обычным листом, просто вы добавили ему ещё два свои метода.

Comment: Вот именно как оперировать этой коллекцией я и не пойму

Answer (score 2):

Поставленную задачу ты реализовал верно.

Поскольку стандартные коллекции не предоставляют `protected` API для расширения и практически не содержат методов, доступных для переопределения, то тебе ничего не остаётся (кроме отражения), как использовать их публичный API - индексаторы, перечислители и методы расширения, вроде LINQ.

Поэтому обычные коллекции чаще не наследуют, а декорируют (оборачивают своим классом), чтобы наружу не торчали методы публичного API родной коллекции, не все из которых верны для производной.

Но это уже проблема постановки задачи.